# SonataBlock, SonataAdmin and Other Sonata bundles keep showing "Validation" error

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

Compile Error: Declaration of Sonata\FormatterBundle\Block\FormatterBlockService::validateBlock() must be compatible with Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockAdminServiceInterface::validateBlock(Sonata\CoreBundle\Validator\ErrorElement $errorElement, Sonata\BlockBundle\Model\BlockInterface $block)

**At the same time:**

PHP Fatal error: Declaration of Sonata\AdminBundle\Block\AdminListBlockService::validateBlock() must be compatible with Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockServiceInterface::validateBlock(Sonata\AdminBundle\Validator\ErrorElement $errorElement, Sonata\BlockBundle\Model\BlockInterface $block) in /phpProjects/vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Block/AdminListBlockService.php on line 105

Here is my composer.json

```
    "php": ">=5.4",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "1.1.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/core-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "~2.2",
    "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "~2.1",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.3@dev",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "~2.3@dev",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "~2.2",
    "sonata-project/exporter": "1.*",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "~2.3@dev",
    "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "~2.3@dev",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "~0.11",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "~1.5@dev",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "~1.4@dev",
    "jms/translation-bundle": "1.1.*@dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "~1.1",
    "genemu/form-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
    "wbx/file-bundle": "dev-master",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution, add dependency **only directly use**

I write to below

```
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "3.0.1",
    "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "~2.2",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "3.0.1",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-mongodb-admin-bundle": "3.0.0"
```

SonataAdminBundle is SonataUserBundle's dependency. Remove SonataAdminBundle and let SonataUserBundle install the bundle. The others the same...

This is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. It seems that something has changed in "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.3@dev" within last 2 days and now its failing (this setup worked 2 days ago). I rolled back to sonata 2.2 which is working. I suggest creating an issue on github.

---

EDIT:
Today I had to change Sonata to latest version. This setup also works:

```
"sonata-project/core-bundle": "dev-master",
"sonata-project/block-bundle": "dev-master",
"sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
"sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "dev-master",
"sonata-project/jquery-bundle": "dev-master",
"sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
```

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I've experienced same problem, supposed to be related with yesterday morning updates, today I've changed my composer.json and this is my working configuration:

```
"sonata-project/core-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
"sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.4.*@dev",
"sonata-project/user-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
"sonata-project/doctrine-mongodb-admin-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
"sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "2.1.*@dev",
"sonata-project/block-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
"sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
"sonata-project/cache-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
"sonata-project/seo-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
"sonata-project/notification-bundle": "~2.3@dev",
"symfony-cmf/routing-bundle": "~1.4@dev",
"sonata-project/page-bundle": "2.4.*@dev",
"sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "2.2.*@dev"
```

Comment: Yes... Your dependencies and removing Sonata Formatter Bundle is the solution... I did try all versions (2.4.x-dev, 2.3.x-dev, 2.3.3, 2.3.2 etc...) Sonata Formatter Bundle and nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, and This is the way I solved it.

```
    "php": "^5.3.9|^7.0",
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.8",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "^1.1",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "~1.0",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf": "1.3.*",
    "symfony-cmf/simple-cms-bundle": "^1.3",
    "symfony-cmf/create-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "~1.1",
    "nelmio/alice": "~1.0",
    "symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle": "^1.1",
    "symfony/security-acl": "^3.0",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.3@dev",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-phpcr-admin-bundle": "^1.2.6",
    "symfony-cmf/menu-bundle": "^2.0"
```

For now, it is working.